# How to print out the cell value from excel using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is the code im using to diff two dataframes, but not sure how i can get the mismatched values cell location.

```
file=[random1.csv,random2.csv]

li=[]
for filename in file:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

df1=li[0]
df2=li[1]


print("{} comparing with {}".format(file[0],file[1]))
df3 = df2[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
print(df3)

print("{} comparing with {}".format(file[1],file[0]))
df4 = df1[df2.ne(df1).any(axis=1)]
print(df4)

output
random1.csv comparing with random2.csv
   name  age  address
1     2   22        2
4     5    6        3
9    10   89       10
random2.csv comparing with random1.csv
   name  age  address
1     2   22        1
4     5    6        2
9    10   89       11
```

kindly help on this!!
p.s : Im a newbie :)